# How to chain ssh with sudo sudosh?

Tags: ssh, sudo, sudosh

I have to connect to a server say SERVER3. To do this,

```
ssh $SERVER1
sudo -u $USER1 sudosh
ssh $SERVER2
sudo -u $USER2 sudosh
ssh $SERVER3
```

I have to repeat this set of commands quite frequently. Is there a way to have these commands as a one line command which I can alias?

Comment: So far, I've figured out ssh -t $SERVER1 "sudo -u $USER1 sudosh"

Comment: why not put into a file and run the file?

Comment: I've already tried that. It doesn't work. It runs all the commands on my pc. So, the remaining commands are left hanging on my local machine until I logout of the ssh.

Comment: no, you do those ssh -t w/ sudo commands in the file.

Comment: @strobelight That happens even when I call them in the file.